# Two counters in a for loop for C#

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop, counter

Hi couldn't find it for C#, I am trying something like that

```
for (int j = mediumNum; j < hardNum; j++; && int k = 0; k < mediumNum; k++);
```

but it does not work. Any valid method???

Comment: just want to use two different counters in a loop.

Comment: while loop is looking like a good option here.....

Answer (score 40, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you want this:

`for (int j = mediumNum, k = 0; j < hardNum && k < mediumNum; j++, k++)`

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, although I would probably never use it

Answer (score 9):

It might express your intent better to use a `while` loop, perhaps making the code a little easier to read:

```
int j = mediumNum;
int k = 0;
while (j < hardNum && k < mediumNum)
{
    //...
    j++;
    k++;
}
```

Comment: I agree, well described intent is much better than jam eveything on to one line.

Comment: I prefer the `while` loop for clarity; nesting it on one line is hard to scan.

Comment: @PaulPhillips: The community at large seems to prefer your solution :)  Probably because it's kind of clever.  I've never seen that comma notation in the loop arguments like that.  Can't say I can think of a need for it off the top of my head (though I can't even think of the last time I used `for` instead of `foreach` these days), but it's interesting to know it exists.

Answer (score 8):

This is what you want

```
for (int j = mediumNum, k = 0; j < hardNum && k < mediumNum; j++, k++)
```

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you know for sure that both loops always terminate at the same time.  If not, the body of the loop will have to account for that.

```
int j;
int k;
for (j = mediumNum, k = 0; j < hardNum && k < mediumNum; j++, k++);
```